# How to schedule tasks in java?

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks

I want to list a hard disk file when receiving broadcast from the system(in my situation, it is android).

The problem is that when I get the broadcast, this hard disk may not be well prepared, so when I read this root file of hard disk, it doesn't exist. So I need to delay my task if this file doesn't exist.

```
if (timerTask != null) return;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        File udisk = file;
        if (!udisk.exists) {
            // This file do not exist now, delay again
            // But how to delay again?
            return;
        }

        // This file has already well prepared, so let's read it
        // timerTask = null;
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000);
```

But I have two problems:

1. **How can I delay again**, if the root file has not well prepared?
2. I need to cancel the task if I get the broadcast that the hard disk is removed. But we may have more than one hard disks, so I may need to have more than one task, so when I cancel the task, which one should I cancel?

Comment: At least for the second question, have you even opened [TimeTask javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) at all? It has a very hard to miss method named `cancel()`.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin sorry, I do know the `cancel` method, I have updated the question.

Comment: Methods for scheduling tasks are very different on Android and Java SE.

Comment: @chrylis I think Android can support javase completely.

Comment: @roger You're mistaken.